# Understanding 尺換算15秒

Tags: meaning

From Oshi no ko. ch. 137, a movie director gives thought about what happened in a brief 15 second ad lib scene:

[image]

I am not sure what meaning the prefix 尺換算 add to 15秒. I understand that 尺 is a unit of measurement for distance and 秒 is a unit of measurement for time. They are incompatible units, so I can't make sense of conversion.

Comment: FYI: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13254086733

Comment: 尺 as jargon refers to the "*final/allocated* length" of a video/movie. This person is internally calculating how her アドリブ amounts to the final product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[尺](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B0%BA_%28%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%8F%29/#jn-101724) here should mean just *length*:

> ２ 長さ。たけ。「—が足りない」「—を測る」

For example, in the context of shooting videos, 尺が足りない = the video is too short. Similarly, 尺換算 means *in terms of the (video) length*. 換算 suggests that the speaker thinks in terms of the video length after edit, i.e. converting raw video into the finished video. (I don't know the manga, and not sure if it is a video, but it should be something similar.)

So verbosely, the part means something like *in the ad-lib acting that spans over 15 seconds of the video after edit*.